# swap files instead of cp with temp file?

Tags: linux, files

There is this famous entry level programming exercise where you're asked to swap two variables. The obvious solution is to use a third, ephemeral variable. But if your language has something like tuples, you can write a very simple helper function that returns its arguments in reversed order:

```scala
def swap(a: Int, b: Int): (Int, Int) = (b, a)
val (two, one) = swap(1, 2) // => (2, 1)
```

I wonder if the same is possible for file operations on Linux. If e.g. I have a configurations that I want to exchange depending on the situation, is there a command that takes two filenames and swaps their contents?
For example, imagine file a.txt has the content "Hello" while b.txt reads "World". After calling what I'd call `swap` here, I would expect a.txt to contain "World" and b.txt "Hello".

The issue is way harder to research than I originally thought because swap partitions dominate all search results.

Comment: Do you want to swap the contents of the files, or the file names? Superficially the same effect but most definitely not the same when considering linked files, permissions, etc

Comment: Excellent question. Would depend on the task, I guess.

Comment: It's your question; which are you looking for?

Comment: In my particular use case, it really doesn't matter. Both files are in the same directory and just plain text. For a more general approach, swapping the contents of the files would conform much better to my expectations than just exchanging the names.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a Linux-specific system call able to do this, at the kernel level.

The relevant system call is [`renameat2()`](https://manpages.debian.org/renameat2.2.en.html) which is a Linux-specific extension to `renameat()` and can be used with an additional specific flag to address this question. It was added in Linux 3.15 and the glibc support in glibc 2.28.

> [`RENAME_EXCHANGE`](https://manpages.debian.org/renameat2.2#RENAME_EXCHANGE)
>
> Atomically exchange *oldpath* and *newpath*. Both pathnames must exist but
> may be of different types (e.g., one could be a non-empty directory
> and the other a symbolic link).

There might be further limitations on which filesystem can support this feature. This [git search](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/log/?qt=grep&q=RENAME_EXCHANGE) tells about support in various filesystems added since 2014: ext4, fuse, f2fs, shmem/tmpfs, xfs, gfs2, overlayfs, btrfs, ubifs, affs ...

Without proper command to use this syscall, here's an example in Python that is very architecture specific (amd64/x86_64) where all symbols were resolved "by hand" (with `SYS_renameat2` = 316 in this architecture etc.) to atomically swap files named `a` and `b`, with `strace` showing what would be done with the system call in C:

```
$ echo Hello > a.txt; echo World > b.txt
$ cat a.txt
Hello
$ cat b.txt
World
$ strace -e trace=renameat2 python3 -c 'import ctypes; libc = ctypes.CDLL(None); libc.syscall(316, -100, b"a.txt", -100, b"b.txt", 2);'
renameat2(AT_FDCWD, "a.txt", AT_FDCWD, "b.txt", RENAME_EXCHANGE) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
$ cat a.txt
World
$ cat b.txt
Hello
```

Of course using a [proper library](https://github.com/jordemort/python-renameat2) would [simplify](https://python-renameat2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) this Python example.

Comment: I had this feeling that if I write "it doesn't exist", someone would soon come and point out that there actually is one. And it only took 23 minutes, even! :D

Answer (score 9):

I don't think there's such a **standard** system call. [There is one on Linux, though.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/673601/170373)

Having or not having a dedicated system call is important, since while you can of course do `rename(a, tmp); rename(b, a); rename(tmp, b);` on any system, it's not atomic. Another process running at the same time might e.g. try to open `a` just after it was renamed away, and it'd get a "file not found" error. Even if you replace that first `rename()` with `link()`, making sure that `a` exists all the time, another process might be able to open both `a` and `b` and get the same file.

Luckily, swapping two files isn't often needed (I'm not sure swapping two variables is that common a need either). Instead, a more common need is replacing the content behind a single file name without leaving a point where a reader would get partial, mixed or missing data. And that's easily done with `rename()`, `link()` or `symlink()`.

With your example of changing from one set of configuration to another, you could have a symbolic link that points to the active configuration, and then atomically replace the link.

E.g. if you have

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu  6 Oct 17 21:07 conf1
-rw-r--r-- 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 13 Oct 17 21:07 conf2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu  5 Oct 17 21:07 current -> conf1
```

then `ln -sf conf2 current` will atomically change it to

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu  6 Oct 17 21:07 conf1
-rw-r--r-- 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 13 Oct 17 21:07 conf2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu  5 Oct 17 21:07 current -> conf2
```

And similarly, you could instead have `conf1` and `current` as hard links to the same file, and replace the link with `ln -f conf2 current`.

Comment: A.B.'s answer is more detailed, so I'm picking it as the correct solution, but your explanation made me go for `ln -sf` in my context. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to avoid *a copy of the file contents* I can think of two ways to achieve this with files.

1. use `mv` to rename the files via an ephemeral file (the contents aren't copied).
2. use a symbolic link, similar to a pointer and explicitly set which config you require rather than swap. eg

```
    
    $ ls
    a.txt  b.txt  define_setcfg.bash
    $ cat a.txt 
    hello
    $ cat b.txt
    world
    $ cat define_setcfg.bash 
    function setcfg () {
    echo Setting config to $1 # Should check that $1 is set to valid cfg filename
    ln -sf $1 actual.cfg       # create symbolic link of $1 named actual.cfg
    }   
    
    $ source ./define_setcfg.bash # define the function in the current bash
    $ setcfg b.txt # use the function setcfg
    Setting config to b.txt
    $ ls -l # check what we have now
    total 12
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 username username   5 Oct 17 18:33 actual.cfg -> b.txt
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 username username   6 Oct 17 18:08 a.txt
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 username username   6 Oct 17 18:08 b.txt
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 161 Oct 17 18:25 define_setcfg.bash
    $ setcfg a.txt # use the function providing a.txt as parameter 1
    Setting config to a.txt
    $ ls -l # check what we have now
    total 12
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 username username   5 Oct 17 18:34 actual.cfg -> a.txt
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 username username   6 Oct 17 18:08 a.txt
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 username username   6 Oct 17 18:08 b.txt
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 161 Oct 17 18:25 define_setcfg.bash
    $
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a command would be easy to write, so I suspect a number exists. But why?

What is the problem that you actually needs to solve? In most cases there are much better ways.

If you have a program that reads a file with a specific name, and you want two versions, what I normally do is to have both versions in the filesystem with names indicating their usability and a symlink to one of them with the name the program that actually uses. Then I can change between them just by updating the symlink (with `ln -sf`).

Comment: I don't think such a function would be easy to write quite as the OP is asking. Since they are asking for it without a third name. There's no atomic swap and exchanging two names would need that third name. Without it, one file would momentarily have no name and you can't add file names to a file which no longer has any name.

Comment: For my use case, I actually might just go with the `ln -sf` solution, but theoretically speaking, @PhilipCouling is right that working with a third file has important downsides.